# Why "Enter a Question" in Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I want to browse questions which have certain keywords in the title using the 'sql' tag. I enter the keywords in the title box and 'sql' as a tag and hit Submit. I get a "Enter a question" error message. What's that for??

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're on the "Ask a Question" page (which, confusingly, does not have a title). To search, use the left nav drawer to choose a site (in this case, probably Stack Overflow), and then use the "Search Questions" box on that page.